# how to display an image without resource image yet

Tags: java, android, string, image

I have created an `ImageView` which in my Layout, it's id is "J", yet it doesn't have a image to display. In the same Layout there is a `EditText` and a `Button`, once there is something written on the `EditText` and the user press the button I want a condition(if and else) to check the text/string that the `EditText` has and if is equal to, lets say "A", it will display an image by using the `ImageView` of J(Which is already initialized), but I don't know how to.

```
public void ABC(View view){//What happens when the Button is clicked;
    EditText A = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.A);
    String AA = A.getText().toString().toUpperCase();//Alternative String
    ImageView J=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.J);
    if (AA.equals("A"){
        //PROBLEM:HERE THE CODE DISPLAYS THE IMAGE USING 'J', but I don't know how.
    }else{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change `edittext` string to **uppercase** because you are comparing "A" as

```
String AA = A.getText().toString().toUpperCase();//Alternative String
```

And then display image as

```
if (AA.equals("A"){
J.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
}else{

}
```

where `my_image.png` in project's **drawable** folder.